# Ajax call changes URL and reloads page in chrome

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I am making a ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Monitoring/addZone",
                type: "POST",
                data: { workspaceID: workspaceID, zone: name }
            }).success(function (result) {
                uploadDiv.innerHTML = result;
            }).error(function (result) {
                uploadDiv.innerHTML = result.responseText;
            });
```

This works fine in Firefox but in chrome it changes the url (adds the sent parameters) and I have no idea why. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: what are the new parameters?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich the new parameters are wierd, I dont know where they come from but it's not what I'm sending to the server nor what I'm getting from it. It adds: `?MACRO+ENODEB=1&METRO+ENODEB=1&MME=1` where the names are a name in my page model and 1 is their index (not sure how much sense this made for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

Aparently setting `type="button"` to my button solved my problem. I'm guessing it was trying to submit the form instead of going to the `onclick` function.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the name of the js file ? 
If [dynamic] gets added to it while the code is still running, then it is a well knowing debugging issue of VS 2012. You may try updating visual studio.
This [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/23e70e79-970d-423f-b434-12681b88ef2c/visual-studio-2012-debug-runs-old-code) may help you if the issue is the same.

Comment: Thank you, I added another `jquery` file to the project and that must be the problem

Comment: can i please know the reason for down vote? it ll help, if nothing else.

Comment: sorry but it's not just a debugging issue, it appears after publishing as well and I didn't yet have the time to read the link you've sent me